# Swift - PageViewController drag animation

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm currently trying to implement a PageViewController just like in the example below (I assume they're using one as well).

My code is set up, but I'm still struggling to get the animation right: to be exact that (just like in the example) when you swipe the main view away, it seems the view on the left was underneath the main the whole time. How do they still display a little from the main ViewController?

Additionally I've recognized that swiping seems a lot more abrupt than in my app, as if there were magnets on the edge.

**Do I have to work with constraints or does it take coding?**

Is it even a PageViewController or solely a subview inside of a view?

[image: gif]

My code in case it's needed:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "timelineView")
        let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView")

        return [vc1, vc2]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self

        if let secondViewController = viewControllerList[1] as? MainViewController {
            self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            secondViewController.buttonAdd.action = #selector(addData(_:))
            secondViewController.buttonReminder.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToReminder(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            secondViewController.buttonSettings.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToSettings(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            secondViewController.buttonUser.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToProfile(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        }
    }


    @objc func addData(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToAdd", sender: self)
    }

    @objc func goToReminder(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNotifications", sender: self)
    }

    @objc func goToSettings(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSettings", sender: self)
    }

    @objc func goToProfile(_ sender: Any) {
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToEdit", sender: self)
        } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToProfile", sender: self)
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }



        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

Comment: The thing in your gif is not a UIPageViewController. You’ll have to start all over.

Comment: @matt what is it? A subview? Whats the correct term for this, so that I can google it.

Comment: I don’t know what the surrounding view controller architecture is. But what you are seeing is an interactive transition animation.

Comment: @matt Thank‘s a lot!